# Sql query with where clause execution

Tags: database, oracle, sql

I have a query like :

```
(q1)
select a,b,c,d from abc
where param='x'

union

(q2)
select e,f,g,h from abc
where param='y'
```

I want to know if value of `<param>='y'` would query1 get executed ??
This is because the recodset "abc" is very very big and actual query involves 5-6 unions on the same parameter(u may see that only one query data is being needed at a time). So if the data is being fetched from all the queries and the filtered according to where clause then it would be a big overhead, whereas if filtered before then only one out of 5 queries actually get executed.

Thanks 
Himanshu

Comment: Moreover i am using Oracle DB(id that effects the answer)

Comment: Try to read more on basic SQL concepts; in the meantime for each SQL you can issue EXPLAIN ... and the RDBMS will show you a plan (which will require you to learn a few more concepts, but in the long run is really useful to know if you want to understand subtleties of SQL vs real data access paths and algorithms).

Comment: I go this link . 
This one clears about bind variables
http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Answer (score 2):

If you write something like

```
where 1 = 2
```

which can be evaluated without touching the database, then Oracle will be clever enough to skip accessing the tables.

This should even work with bind variables.

```
where ? = ?
```

Of course, as soon as columns are involved, it will have to go look at the data.

Comment: That Means i can use as many unions in the way without having much of an overhead?

Comment: The query optimizer should be able to find and discard dead code in your query. Overhead compared to what? It will be lighter still if you eliminate the useless part yourself.

Comment: While writing such a query(involving unions) my concern was the overhead of fetching of data from tables without filtering(i.e. useless data). your answer solves my concern to much extent.

Comment: I am using bind parameter to get the data from query as per the need and that is where unions are used.

Answer (score 2):

If 'param' is a column in abc, it would help greatly when you index that column.

But the biggest performance impact in your query is probably the 'union', because Oracle has to filter out duplicate rows. Depending on the size of your result set, this is quite a heavy operation (sorting, removing duplicates). If you're not concerned with duplicate results (or if they're simply impossible because of the definition of the queries), use 'union all':

```
select a,b,c,d from abc
union all
select e,f,g,h from abc
```

Comment: <param> is a bind variable(not a column)

Comment: Query is such that only one out of all the unions data gets fetched depending on the value of <param>.

Comment: It would seem a better solution to me to change the software to execute the right query instead of letting the database figure it out based on a bind parameter. Is that possible?

Comment: This is where i am stuck. Its really hard to change it without guarantee of the correct result:( . That is the reason i have put up this question.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? What program is executing this query? Where does the bind variable come from? Programming language? What else can you change besides the query (i.e. outside the database)?

Comment: @Martin, good advices on both matters, esp. you can never emphasize enough that UNION and UNION ALL are very different things both performance and result-wise.

Comment: I have a dropdown. Depending on the selection i need data from a result set. Different Unions are basically applying different "group by" clauses + some computations(sum/avg etc) . So one way could be manually programming and putting the "group by" behaviour in UI layer(which i am not in favour of). Other is keeping 5 different connections to DB open and fetching data directly as per selection from dropdown(the overhead here would be greater imho)

Comment: Is this a client/server application? What platform? 5 different connections? "group by" in the UI layer? You're losing me on this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (
select 1 INDICATOR,
       a, b, c
from abc
union all
select 2 INDICATOR,
       a, b, c
from abc)
where indicator = 1;
```

This won't execute the second query in the union. As you can see in the execution plan, there is a **Filter** which says "null is not null". However there is a significant overhead with many unions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is lazy programming and you are trying to make the database do the application's job.  A simple "if" statement with a bunch of concatenations is all you need.

Comment: I think it's presumptuous to say it's "lazy" - you don't know the context in which this query is required. For one thing, it might be in a context that doesn't permit PL/SQL. Plus, where is it said that doing this kind of thing must be the "application's" job?

Answer (score 0):

The question suggests to me, that you want to avoid two full table scans over the data set.
This technique **might** help you.

```
WITH
base AS
(
    SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h FROM abc -- all columns of interest
    WHERE param IN ('x', 'y')       -- all rows of interest
),
q1 AS
(
    select a,b,c,d from base        -- one specific subset
    where param='x'
),
q2 AS
(
    select e,f,g,h from base        -- the other specific subset
    where param='y'
)
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM abc             -- then the union of the sets

UNION

SELECT e,f,g,h FROM abc             -- that you are interested in.
```

As you are doing lookups on param, an index would be of great value, allowing the FULL TABLE SCAN to be replaced by a less costly INDEX scan.

If the set of distinct values in param are small, it may be of benefit to build [histograms](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_otn_cbo_p4.htm).

As in all things Oracle, your mileage may vary.

I would be interested in hearing how it all turns out for you.

Comment: Thanks. I had decided to fo with my current implementation.Now Looking into your suggestion. Hope this thing works out correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, Oracle will remove dead code branches from your query after having evaluated the bind variable. You can replace the union with "union all" (not that it should matter anyway), but the intent of the developer is shown more clearly (I, the developer expected no duplicates here).

One open question (to me anyway) is: Can you know for sure that the data type of "a" matches "e" and "b" matches "f" etcetera?

Actually, I have never implemeneted this myself, only read about it so someone want to validate what I'm saying. But a completely different approach could be to create a stored procedure which takes the parameter.
The procedure would have one cursor for each expected value of param. Then you can test (IF) the value of the param and return a ref cursor.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by data type matching.In unions all colums should be same and if we dont need one particular column we do "null as <column name>". So effectively "a" is same as "e" and "b" is same as "f".
I cannot create stored procedure. Can only use SQL.
Thanks

Comment: You didn't share DDL, so I couldn't know.